# I am not able to find what is the problem with the code. ERROR: TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-reducer

Error says Inside TodoForm component dispatch is not a function. I have tried but not working. dispatch is a function from App component.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.ADD_TODO:
      return [...state, action.payload]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
const App = () => {
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [])
  return (
    <todoContext.Provider value={todos, dispatch}>
      <TodoForm />
      <Todos />
    </todoContext.Provider>
  )
}

const TodoForm = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (todoText === "") { return alert("Plz...Enter todo!!!") }
    dispatch({ 
      type: ACTIONS.ADD_TODO,
      payload: todoText
    })
    setTodoText("")
  }
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have to access it from the context, it doesn't just make those values globally scoped within children components. See the docs on [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: I have accessed it from the context but i cants show you that because of too much code in question, but i find out the problem which was Provider's value attribute should have object not to different value. i wite this ```value={todos, dispatch}``` insted of this ```value={{todos, dispatch}}```